# Separate Database table vs serialized key:value pair

Tags: python, database, database-design, sqlalchemy, relational-database

I am working on designing a relational database for a meal scheduler web application.
I have it 99% set up, but I am wondering if to use a separate table for the "meal type" entries.
To sum it up, users can add their own meal type(breakfast, snack, dinner) arbitrarily, in any order, and I am currently storing them in a simple list (ordered with javascript in the frontend for convenience).
It won't have more than half a dozen elements at worst (who even plans more than 6 meals a day anyway), so I am saving it all in the database's settings table, which contains rows as key:value pairs.
In this case, it's 'meals': [json string representing the python list]

The problem is that every scheduled recipe needs to be qualified by meal type.

```
id_scheduled_meal
id_recipe
meal_type
```

Right now, I'd have to use the exact string saved in the key:value pair in order to associate it with a specific meal type, so meal_type would be "Breakfast" or "Snack", rather than an id. It feels like too much redundant data.

At the same time, I am not sure it would be good to create a separate object (Meal) with a separate table (meal), only to add 4-6 entries and 1-3 columns (id, name, position).

Any suggestions? I am happy to clarify, I realize the explanation might not be as clear as it could.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this is pretty opinion based, and the answer will depend on how you want to interact with the data.  If you plan on writing queries that include the meal type, then you might save yourself some pain and just do the extra table, though managing/saving items will be more complex.  If it's just a list that you plan on doing everything with in python (or whatever), then serialising a list and saving the text might be the better choice.  Whether the extra redundant space will adversely affect you will depend on your application and requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Right now the only thing that leaves me undecided is dealing with removing those entries. I would have to compare the previous list, see which ones have been removed, and update the database entries that used it with some generic "unassigned". At the same time as you say I can't just save the list and be content if it's a separate object type. Even with that, it's usually something users set up once and forget. or twice in a year if they change their habits